# Create a list variable with mutate in R

Tags: r, list, dplyr

I want to use mutate to create a list variable/column in a dataframe (actually, a `tibble`). Here is a simplified version of my problem:

```
Y = c(12,10,15)
df = tibble(z=seq(1,20)) %>% mutate( zz = ifelse(z>Y,z,Y) )
```

In other words, the variable `zz` in `df` must contain a list of 3 values where each value of `Y` is replaced by `z` if and only if `z>Y`.
However, `mutate` does not produce a column of 3-element lists. It gives me a warning and produces a vector of 60 elements.

Comment: Latest `dplyr` produces a tibble with 20 rows, at least for me. The problem is with R's native auto-repeat - try `seq(20) > c(12, 10, 15)`, that's what you're basically doing. If you used the `tidyverse` version - `if_else` - at least you end up with a failure and not a bogus result with a warning. If you want to do per element comparison of the vector with the `Y`, you really need to use `map`, albeit somewhat differently than r.user suggests.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to combine mutate with map and pmax is less verbose than if_else:

```
df <- df %>%
  mutate(zz = map(z, ~pmax(.x, Y)))
```